# Remove duplicate value from javascript array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have one function which is dynamically fired and returns an array like:

```
45
45,46
45,46,47
```

Here i want to get only single value mean new first **45** fired second time **46** fired Next time **47**

Is there any way to get this?

I have tried this:

```
function mydata(treeId){
    console.log(treeId); // contain random data like 45,46,47
    resultPush = [];
    $.each(treeId, function(i, el){
        if($.inArray(el, resultPush) === -1){
            resultPush.push(el);

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Is treeId an array or a string or what is it?

Comment: Which function does generate those arrays - `myData` or are those the passed `treeId`s?

Comment: @javid, what do you want your output to be? `[45,46,47]` or `[[45],[46],[47]]`?

Answer (score 0):

You can try with [`$.unique()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.unique/):

```
$.unique(treeId); // unique elements
```

Comment: @hsz And just when you thought you'd discovered everything in jQuery!  I had completely missed this one!

Answer (score 0):

I have to guess, but I think you want to declare `resultPush` outside of the array so that you can know results from previous calls:

```
var resultPush = [];
function mydata(treeId){
    for (var i=0; i<treeId.length; i++ {
        var el = treeId[i];
        if ($.inArray(el, resultPush) === -1) {
            resultPush.push(el);
            return el;
        }
    }
}
```

```
mydata([45]) // 45
mydata([45,46]) // 46
mydata([45,46,47]) // 47
```

Answer (score 0):

jYou'll need one container array:

```
var container = [];
```

Each time you are pushed numbers:

```
var arr = []; // Contains your numbers...
for (var i = 0, iLen = arr.Length; i < iLen; i++) {
    var exists = false;
    for (var j = 0, jLen = container.Length; j < jLen; j++) {
        if (container[j] == arr[i]) { exists = true; break; }
    }
    if (exists == false) {
         container.push(arr[i]);
    }
}
```

If someone knows a better way, I'm all ears!

Comment: Instead of the tedious inner loop, you should simply use `indexOf` or, like the OP, `$.inArray`.

Comment: @Bergi, thanks! Guess it just comes down to outright performance.  Yours is certainly slightly easier to read and i suspect the array size we're talking of here negates any potential performance difference. :-)